# I don't get how turnstiles are able to work

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, semaphore

I'm reading the little book of semaphores and reached the following code:

```
rendezvous

mutex . wait ()
    count = count + 1
mutex . signal ()

if count == n: barrier . signal ()

barrier . wait ()// the part i don't get
barrier . signal ()

critical point
```

barrier is semaphore(0) and mutex is semaphore(1)
the book says that this code works, but i have no clue how. if n-1 threads reach the `barrier.wait()`, the barrier will equal -(n-1) and at for the last thread where count == n, it signals the barrier, but wont that only make the barrier -(n-1)+1 which is still negative for most values of n. apparently this is supposed to start to let the threads go past one by one, but i am confused. can someone explain

Comment: The `barrier.signal()` after the `barrier.wait()` lets the next thread through, and then it lets the next thread through, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> if n-1 threads reach the `barrier.wait()`, the barrier will equal -(n-1)

Absolutely not.  It is a basic property of semaphores, which your book taught long before this point, that the value of a semaphore cannot be reduced below 0.  A thread attempting to decrement a semaphore when its value is already zero will *block* until the value is positive.

> for the last thread where count == n, it signals the barrier, but wont that only make the barrier -(n-1)+1 which is still negative for most values of n

No.  When the last thread makes it through, it will increase the barrier semaphore from 0 to 1.  That will allow either that same thread itself or one of those already blocked at `barrier.wait()` to complete a `barrier.wait()`.  That briefly reduces the semaphore's value to 0 again, but each thread that reaches that point continues by incrementing the `barrier` semaphore again, letting one more thread through.